# instagram api ruby subscription tag post access object_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, subscription, instagram-api

the problem that i have is that when i post a picture on Instagram with the good hastag# of my subscription, i receive the notification in my callback but i can't access the object_id in the params. Here is the line that i receive :

Parameters: {"_json"=>[{"changed_aspect"=>"media", "object"=>"tag", "object_id"=>"mytag", "time"=>1439341303, "subscription_id"=>19499294, "data"=>{}}], "subscription"=>{}}

Here's my ruby code :

def process_subscription

```
    if params["hub.challenge"]
        render :text => params["hub.challenge"]
    else
        @test_tag_name =  params["object_id"]
    end
```

end

But the @test_tag_name is always to null.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those exact params, this would work: `params["_json"][0]["object_id"]`

But you'll probably need to adjust based on what `params["_json"]` will return in the general case (I'm not familiar with that API). For example, you should probably iterate over the array it returns rather than grabbing the first element.

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't worked. This -> params["_json"][0]["object_id"]    returned me this - >   "70267297418320".    I don't know where this number came from

Comment: Nevermind, your solution worked ! I got "70267297418320" because i've used params["_json"][0].object_id instead of params["_json"][0]["object_id"]. thank you very much